# JavaScript UTM parameters from iframe URL - URL querystring format problem

Tags: javascript, utm

I trying to extract UTM parameters from the URL querystring of an iframe URL however the querystring always includes "#038;" which seems to prevent JavaScript from getting more than first parameter, so I can only get utm_campaign and cannot get the other parameters(utm_medium, utm_source etc.). The URL querystring looks like:

```
?utm_campaign=testCampaign&#038;utm_medium=testMedium&#038;utm_source=testMedium&#038;utm_content=testContent&#038;utm_term=testTerm&#038;
```

I have tried using the followng script.

How can I remove "#038;" from the URL querystring?

```js
function getUtmParams(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\&amp;/gi,''));
    }
    var utmArray = ['utm_campaign','utm_medium','utm_source','utm_content','utm_term'];
    for (var i = 0; i < utmArray.length; i++) {
      console.log("b " + getUtmParams(utmArray[i]));
        document.querySelector("div." + utmArray[i] + " input[type=hidden]").value = getUtmParams(utmArray[i]);
        console.log("div." + utmArray[i] + " input[type=hidden]" + getUtmParams(utmArray[i]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote the script to split the UTM parameters by `&#038;`. So I can now acess all the UTM params as expected.

Hope this helps someone.

```js
(function() {
var url = window.location.href;
var queryparams = url.split('?')[1];
var params = queryparams.split('&#038;');
var pair = null,
    data = [];
params.forEach(function(d) {
    pair = d.split('=');
    data.push({key: pair[0], value: pair[1]});
});
console.log(data);
var utmCampaign = data.find(item => item.key === "utm_campaign");
var utmMedium = data.find(item => item.key === "utm_medium");
var utmSource = data.find(item => item.key === "utm_source");
var utmContent = data.find(item => item.key === "utm_content");
var utmTerm = data.find(item => item.key === "utm_term");
document.querySelector("div.utm_campaign input[type=hidden]").value = utmCampaign.value;
document.querySelector("div.utm_medium input[type=hidden]").value = utmMedium.value;
document.querySelector("div.utm_source input[type=hidden]").value = utmSource.value;
document.querySelector("div.utm_content input[type=hidden]").value = utmContent.value;
document.querySelector("div.utm_term input[type=hidden]").value = utmTerm.value;
})();
```